# iMac 27″ boots successfully to safe mode only

Tags: macos, imac, startup, crash

**I can only boot my iMac 27″ (end of 2009) in safe mode.**

The problem started in Lion, when the computer suddenly froze. All I can get is the grey screen, which turns black after a while.

I upgraded (in safe mode) to Mavericks 10.9.2. Still the same problem.

Took away all Launch Agents and Daemons that are not Apple (both in System and User's), done all the permission repairs, reset memory, fsck and turn the plug off the computer. The only thing I was not able to do is the hardware test (for some reason, the command + D to access the internet testing is not working). I have no external devices or cables attached (though on this log I had a printer).

My 2 TB hard drive is divided in 3 partitions. I have got 2 user accounts.

I have tried a few other tricks from the experts in the discussion boards (including removing all preference files that are non apple, remove all non apple extensions), still no way to start up the computer other than safe boot.

I would like to try and turn off bonjour, as it seems like a MDNSResponder Error. But need a green light from any of you experts.

I am posting the latest system log (on this one, I forgot to unplug the printer)

```
May  4 20:38:05 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1399246685 0
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.bookstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May  4 20:38:45 --- last message repeated 6 times ---
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 2008481 free pages and 72287 wired pages
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f807a5000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80007a5000]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: standard background quantum is 2500 us
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 74
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=2 LocalApicId=2 Enabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=3 LocalApicId=4 Enabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=4 LocalApicId=6 Enabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=5 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=6 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=7 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=8 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: MAC Framework successfully initialized
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Jan 16 2014 20:19:00)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: IOAPIC: Version 0x20 Vectors 64:87
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: ACPI: sleep states S3 S4 S5
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: Turbo Ratios 1144
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: (built 19:46:50 Jan 16 2014) initialization complete
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: pci (build 20:00:24 Jan 16 2014), flags 0x63008, pfm64 (36 cpu) 0xf80000000, 0x80000000
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: console relocated to 0xf80010000
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 9, devices 21 ]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 10, devices 36 ]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: mcache: 4 CPU(s), 64 bytes CPU cache line size
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: mbinit: done [96 MB total pool size, (64/32) split]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Pthread support ABORTS when sync kernel primitives misused
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: FireWire (OHCI) TI ID 823f built-in now active, GUID 40d32dfffe04245e; max speed s800.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: 48B4343E-ADD2-366E-8820-219D2141D0B7
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting on IOProviderClassIOResourcesIOResourceMatchboot-uuid-media
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient: ready
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@1F,2/AppleIntelPchS   eriesAHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IO B lockStorageDriver/Hitachi HDS722020ALA330 Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/Macintosh HD@2
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: BSD root: disk0s2, major 1, minor 2
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000009833 0x5ac 0x8403 0x9833, 2
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device root_device
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    1.518    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0xfd140000)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: ath_get_caps[4044] rx chainmask mismatch actual 3 sc_chainmak 0
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.257313: ath_get_caps[4019] tx chainmask mismatch actual 3 sc_chainmak 0
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261494: Atheros: mac 128.2 phy 13.0 radio 12.0
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261504: Use hw queue 0 for WME_AC_BE traffic
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261510: Use hw queue 1 for WME_AC_BK traffic
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261516: Use hw queue 2 for WME_AC_VI traffic
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261522: Use hw queue 3 for WME_AC_VO traffic
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261529: Use hw queue 8 for CAB traffic
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261534: Use hw queue 9 for beacons
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261612: wlan_vap_create : enter. devhandle=0xd6b8f6b0, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261651: wlan_vap_create : exit. devhandle=0xd6b8f6b0, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261688: ATH tunables:
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: 2.261691:   pullmode[1] txringsize[  256] txsendqsize[1024] reapmin[   32] reapcount[  128]
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    4.521    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    5.362    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0xfd140000)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    8.760    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    9.587    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0xfd140000)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    10.418    The IOUSBFamily gave up enumerating a USB device after 10 retries.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0xfd140000)
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: USBF:    10.418    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: process taskgated[13] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 1596; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 45036
May  4 20:38:44 localhost kernel[0]: VM Swap Subsystem is ON
May  4 20:38:06 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
May  4 20:38:06 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** Shutdown logging is enabled. ***
May  4 20:38:32 localhost hidd[44]: void __IOHIDPlugInLoadBundles(): Loaded 0 HID plugins
May  4 20:38:36 localhost hidd[44]: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
May  4 20:38:44 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[25]: Session 100000 created
May  4 20:38:45 localhost distnoted[65]: # distnote server daemon  absolute time: 28.917725827   civil time: Sun May  4 20:38:33 2014   pid: 65 uid: 0  root: yes
May  4 20:38:46 localhost revisiond[27]: sandbox cache error 3850
May  4 20:38:46 localhost blued[57]: sandbox cache error 11: database disk image is malformed
May  4 20:38:46 localhost ReportCrash[71]: Invoking spindump for pid=13 wakeups_rate=1596 duration=29 because of excessive wakeups
May  4 20:38:47 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
May  4 20:38:47 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished(): 
May  4 20:38:47 localhost spindump[73]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
May  4 20:38:47 localhost spindump[73]: Unable to register Stop Spinning port: 1011
May  4 20:38:47 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting for DSMOS...
May  4 20:38:48 localhost spindump[73]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
May  4 20:38:48 localhost kdc[42]: krb5_kdc_set_dbinfo: failed to create root node: /Local/Default
May  4 20:38:48 localhost com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.Kerberos.kdc[42]): Exited with code: 1
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x8215 FirmwareVersion - 0x0207
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0xec00 ****
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed -- 0xec00 ****
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: init
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: probe
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: start
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0xec00
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][start] -- completed
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: ** Device in slot: SLOT--1 **
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 3
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: MMIO regMap == NULL - fall back to old SMC mode
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHCIController][protectedBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0x1240 -- 0x7800 -- 0xec00 ****
May  4 20:38:49 localhost kernel[0]: DSMOS has arrived
May  4 20:38:50 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[25]: Entering service
May  4 20:38:51 localhost kdc[79]: label: default
May  4 20:38:51 localhost kdc[79]:     dbname: od:/Local/Default
May  4 20:38:51 localhost kdc[79]:     mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
May  4 20:38:51 localhost kdc[79]:     acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
May  4 20:38:52 localhost digest-service[66]: label: default
May  4 20:38:52 localhost digest-service[66]:     dbname: od:/Local/Default
May  4 20:38:52 localhost digest-service[66]:     mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
May  4 20:38:52 localhost digest-service[66]:     acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
May  4 20:38:52 localhost kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
May  4 20:38:52 localhost configd[55]: dhcp_arp_router: en1 SSID unavailable
May  4 20:38:52 localhost configd[55]: network changed.
May  4 20:38:53 Macs-iMac-3.local configd[55]: setting hostname to "Macs-iMac-3.local"
May  4 20:38:53 Macs-iMac-3.local digest-service[66]: digest-request: uid=0
May  4 20:38:53 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.usbmuxd[17]: usbmuxd-327.4 on Feb 12 2014 at 14:54:33, running 64 bit
May  4 20:38:53 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNSResponder mDNSResponder-522.90.2 (Nov  3 2013 18:51:09) starting OSXVers 13
May  4 20:38:55 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Video on device disk0s4
May  4 20:38:56 Macs-iMac-3.local apsd[60]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
May  4 20:38:56 Macs-iMac-3.local aosnotifyd[61]: aosnotifyd has been launched
May  4 20:38:57 Macs-iMac-3.local systemkeychain[94]: done file: /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.done
May  4 20:38:57 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Musicas on device disk0s5
May  4 20:38:58 Macs-iMac-3.local configd[55]: network changed: DNS*
May  4 20:38:58 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May  4 20:38:58 Macs-iMac-3.local stackshot[21]: Timed out waiting for IOKit to finish matching.
May  4 20:38:58 Macs-iMac-3.local awacsd[58]: Starting awacsd connectivity_executables-97 (Aug 24 2013 23:49:23)
May  4 20:38:59 Macs-iMac-3.local airportd[62]: airportdProcessDLILEvent: en1 attached (up)
May  4 20:38:59 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: AtherosNewma40P2PInterface::init name  role 1
May  4 20:38:59 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: AtherosNewma40P2PInterface::init()  role 1
May  4 20:38:59 Macs-iMac-3.local digest-service[66]: digest-request: netr probe 0
May  4 20:38:59 Macs-iMac-3.local digest-service[66]: digest-request: init request
May  4 20:39:00 Macs-iMac-3.local digest-service[66]: digest-request: init return domain: BUILTIN server: MACS-IMAC-3 indomain was: 
May  4 20:39:00 Macs-iMac-3.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
May  4 20:39:01 Macs-iMac-3.local loginwindow[38]: Login Window Application Started
May  4 20:39:01 Macs-iMac-3.local UserEventAgent[11]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
May  4 20:39:02 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: D2D_IPC: Loaded
May  4 20:39:02 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: D2DInitialize succeeded
May  4 20:39:02 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]:   4: Listening for incoming Unix Domain Socket client requests
May  4 20:39:02 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: Adding registration domain 156425616.members.btmm.icloud.com.
May  4 20:39:02 Macs-iMac-3.local kdc[79]: KDC started
May  4 20:39:02 Macs-iMac-3.local awacsd[58]: Configuring lazy AWACS client: 156425616.p07.members.btmm.icloud.com.
May  4 20:39:03 Macs-iMac-3.local networkd[124]: networkd.124 built Aug 24 2013 22:08:46
May  4 20:39:03 Macs-iMac-3.local awacsd[58]: KV HTTP 0
May  4 20:39:06 Macs-iMac-3.local apsd[60]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
May  4 20:39:08 Macs-iMac-3.local mds[34]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May  4 20:39:09 Macs-iMac-3.local awacsd[58]: KV HTTP 0
May  4 20:39:09 Macs-iMac-3.local spindump[73]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
May  4 20:39:10 Macs-iMac-3.local sandboxd[116] ([62]): airportd(62) deny file-read-data /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.506705CD-8AA9-5 340-BEA4-87BBB2A2E261.plist
May  4 20:39:11 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
May  4 20:39:11 Macs-iMac-3.local blued[57]: hostControllerOnline - Number of Paired devices = 5, List of Paired devices = (
        "00-22-41-ce-73-b2",
        "7c-d1-c3-bc-ed-9b",
        "04-f1-3e-e9-76-f5",
        "d4-88-90-f0-2d-96",
        "90-27-e4-f2-fd-53"
    )
May  4 20:39:12 Macs-iMac-3.local blued[57]: link key found for device: 04-f1-3e-e9-76-f5
May  4 20:39:12 Macs-iMac-3.local blued[57]: Save link key for device: 04-f1-3e-e9-76-f5
May  4 20:39:12 Macs-iMac-3.local blued[57]: link key found for device: 7c-d1-c3-bc-ed-9b
May  4 20:39:12 Macs-iMac-3.local blued[57]: Save link key for device: 7c-d1-c3-bc-ed-9b
May  4 20:39:13 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: [BNBMouseDevice::init][80.14] init is complete
May  4 20:39:13 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: [BNBMouseDevice::handleStart][80.14] returning 1
May  4 20:39:13 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchHIDEventDriver::start] entered
May  4 20:39:13 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
May  4 20:39:14 Macs-iMac-3.local blued[57]: [setFeatureWithReportID] Could not set report
May  4 20:39:19 Macs-iMac-3.local awacsd[58]: KV HTTP 0
May  4 20:39:21 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: 76.792776: setWOW_PARAMETERS:wowevents = 2(1)
May  4 20:39:21 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Server is starting up
May  4 20:39:22 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: 77.481213: performCountryCodeOperation: Not connected, scan in progress[0]
May  4 20:39:22 Macs-iMac-3.local locationd[40]: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
May  4 20:39:22 Macs-iMac-3.local locationd[40]: NBB-Could not get UDID for stable refill timing, falling back on random
May  4 20:39:22 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US '.
May  4 20:39:22 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
May  4 20:39:22 Macs-iMac-3.local mds[34]: (Normal) FMW: FMW 0 0
May  4 20:39:23 Macs-iMac-3.local locationd[40]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FA01AD60 Macs-iMac-3.local. (Addr) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FA01B1F0 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FB801B60 Macs-iMac-3.local. (AAAA) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FB801FF0 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.E.F.ip6.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:27 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 10:9a:dd:82:5b:36
May  4 20:39:27 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
May  4 20:39:27 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: 83.354881: apple80211Request[10514] Unsupported ioctl 181
May  4 20:39:27 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 10:9a:dd:82:5b:36
May  4 20:39:27 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
May  4 20:39:28 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
May  4 20:39:28 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Session 256 released (1 references)
May  4 20:39:28 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
May  4 20:39:28 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
May  4 20:39:28 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
May  4 20:39:29 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Found 39 modes for display 0x00000000 [36, 3]
May  4 20:39:29 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
May  4 20:39:29 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: mux_initialize: Couldn't find any matches
May  4 20:39:29 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Found 39 modes for display 0x00000000 [36, 3]
May  4 20:39:29 Macs-iMac-3.local WindowServer[118]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
May  4 20:39:30 Macs-iMac-3.local configd[55]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
May  4 20:39:30 Macs-iMac-3.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1655] en1: SSID 'Apple Network 825b35' making interface primary (protected network)
May  4 20:39:30 Macs-iMac-3.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Evaluating
May  4 20:39:30 Macs-iMac-3.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: en1: Probing 'Apple Network 825b35'
May  4 20:39:30 Macs-iMac-3.local configd[55]: network changed: v4(en1!:10.0.1.5) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
May  4 20:39:31 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: accepted connection on vpn control socket.
May  4 20:39:32 Macs-iMac-3.local ntpd[132]: proto: precision = 1.000 usec
May  4 20:39:32 Macs-iMac-3.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Authenticated
May  4 20:39:33 Macs-iMac-3.local apsd[60]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
May  4 20:39:35 Macs-iMac-3.local mds_stores[129]: (/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T)(Error) IndexCI in void _indexEmergencyUnmap(void *):live.1. marking invalid
May  4 20:39:43 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: utun_ctl_connect: creating interface utun0
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500] (Can't assign requested address).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[4500] (Can't assign requested address).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[4500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500] (Can't assign requested address).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[4500] (Can't assign requested address).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[4500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500] (Can't assign requested address).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[4500] (Can't assign requested address).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[4500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2).
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
May  4 20:40:25 Macs-iMac-3.local warmd[16]: [warmctl_evt_timer_bc_activation_timeout:287] BC activation bcstop timer fired!
May  4 20:40:25 Macs-iMac-3.local warmd[16]: [___bootcachectl_filter_out_sharedio_from_history_block_invoke:2329] Unable to open i386 shared cache: 2 No such file or directory
May  4 20:40:31 Macs-iMac-3 kernel[0]: considerRebuildOfPrelinkedKernel com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib triggered rebuild
May  4 20:40:42 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.jmicron.JMicronATA  101069000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:40:49 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.ATTO.driver.ATTOExpressSASRAID  307029000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:40:49 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.ATTO.driver.ATTOExpressSASHBA3  100059000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:40:49 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.ATTO.driver.ATTOExpressSASHBA  200009000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:40:49 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.ATTO.driver.ATTOExpressPCIUl4  404029000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:40:49 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.ATTO.driver.ATTOCelerityFC  304089000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:40:55 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: kext com.Accusys.driver.Acxxx  300029000 is in exception list, allowing to load
May  4 20:41:16 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.kextcache[154]: Created prelinked kernel /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/kernelcache.
May  4 20:42:17 Macs-iMac-3.local distnoted[161]: # distnote server agent  absolute time: 252.755084619   civil time: Sun May  4 20:42:17 2014   pid: 161 uid: 502  root: no
May  4 20:42:18 Macs-iMac-3.local mdworker[157]: sandbox cache error 3850
May  4 20:42:37 Macs-iMac-3.local distnoted[169]: # distnote server agent  absolute time: 272.385323107   civil time: Sun May  4 20:42:37 2014   pid: 169 uid: 89  root: no
May  4 20:42:38 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.SecurityServer[25]: Session 100005 created
May  4 20:42:38 Macs-iMac-3.local com.apple.SecurityServer[25]: Session 100004 created
May  4 20:42:50 Macs-iMac-3.local mds[34]: (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7faf09848800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/firmwaresyncd.vXiC4Y
May  4 20:45:38 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1399247138 0
```

Comment: For your model the Internet hardware test is not working, check if you have one on your hd, it is in the hidden partition of the hidden recovery.

Comment: Also, could you cleanup that log by: disconnecting all peripheral devices, disable Airport and Bluetooth, and sharing ect, then run the log again.

Comment: If you can, try to boot from an external Drive. Or if you have another mac and a FireWire Cable, Target Disc Mode might be interisting to you. Trying to delete launchd's sounds like a very bad Idea. You never know what is needed and what is not.

Comment: Is this a log of a normal boot that failed or the log of a safe boot?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for your model the Internet hardware test is not working, so check if you have one on your hd, it is in the hidden partition of the hidden recovery. Also, could you cleanup that log by: disconnecting all peripheral devices, disable Airport and Bluetooth, and sharing ect, then run the log again.

If you can, try to boot from an external Drive. Or if you have another mac and a FireWire Cable, Target Disc Mode might be interesting to you. Trying to delete launchd's sounds like a very bad Idea. You never know what is needed and what is not.

Regarding *Shutdown Cause: 3*, it is normally related to hard shutdown.

<sup>Answer assembled from the comments.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a (no Apple) software issue in your account.
Go to Etrecheck.com, read about etrecheck, download it, run it, and post the list here. It will possibly expose the culprit(s).
If the mac will not start, while in Safe Mode again, remove all items from SystemPreferences->Users&Groups->LoginItems.
If that is not enough, in the Safe Mode again, open the Applications folder, uninstall antivirus app, or MacKeeper, or other culprits. Then try again.